# Using X509Certificate for TLS degrading performance considerably

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I'm using C# .NET to upload numerous, large, files from client to server using SslStream.
It's twice as slow as un-encrypted upload. How much delay is normal?

Any suggestions on how to improve the performance of encryption framework? Would lowering the encryption strength of pfx/pvk help? If so how to do it? All tips are welcome.

Edit:
In each client session 1 or multiple files are uploaded. In my test there were 1250. Client uses same SslStream for a session...

Server code:

```
private void OnAcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult result)
{

    var client = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
    Stream stream = client.GetStream();

    if (_cert != null)
    {
    var ssl = new SslStream(stream, false);
    ssl.AuthenticateAsServer(_cert, false, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
    stream = ssl;
    }
    // Processing block
    ...
}
```

Client Code:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginSend(string host, int port, bool bTls, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{

    _client = new TcpClient(host, port) { NoDelay = NoDelay };
    Stream stream = _client.GetStream();

    if (bTls)
    {
    var ssl = new SslStream(stream, false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((o, c, ch, er) => true));
    ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(host);
    stream = ssl;
    }
    // Send all files
    return BeginSend(stream, callback, state);

}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your case establishing new connection (including the TLS handshake) or each file is the problem. You need to use one connection for all files.

Comment: Using one/single connection for all files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the X509 Certificate to cryptography all files sent to server? I think one solution could be using the X509 Certificate just in the beginning in order to exchange a random generated symmetric cryptography key and then use it to cryptography the files to be sent. Just like https does.

Another tip is to see if the cryptographed data is getting too much bigger.

Comment: Initializing SslStream at the begining of the session and using it to upload all the files in that batch/session.